# Screen loses permissions after ssh disconnection

Tags: ssh, permissions, file-permissions, gnu-screen

I have a long running bash script that I run on a remote host with `screen`, so I can log off ssh. When I come back after some time (after logging off), the screen terminal no longer has permissions to access my files and folders.

What's causing this, and is there a way to avoid it?

OS: Scientific Linux CERN SLC release 6.9 (Carbon), using the Andrew File System.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Encrypted home?

Comment: Moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375007/screen-loses-permissions-after-ssh-disconnection.

Comment: that's a known pain to many who have their home dir on afs. 1) i usually have screen running on host A and ssh inside of screen to host B (without using kerberos as ssh authentication), such that host B sees me logged in with the locally generated token. 2) there are [these](https://lhcb.github.io/analysis-essentials/shell/persistent-screen.html) instructions at cern, though some users report it fails for them when the key file is on afs. 3) try `pagsh.krb -c 'kinit && tmux'` (or screen instead of tmux)